# How to Unit Test AspNetCore 8.0 Application Startup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

In .net 6, I would unit test my api by using the startup class in a webhost builder so I could verify configuration and DI implemntation.

However, with the new sleek way of using the program.cs, upgrading my api from .net 6 to .net 8 has broken my unit tests.  The idea is that I would only have to maintain how the app is started up in one location and the unit test then uses that same configuration.

Old way of starting the application:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostForDependencyInjectionTests(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            if (args != null)
            {
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            }
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        // Add a new service provider configuration
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
        {
            options.ValidateScopes = true;
            options.ValidateOnBuild = true;
        });
```

Unit Test:

```
[TestCase("Development")]
[TestCase("Production")]
public void DependencyRegistrationIsValid(string env)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", env);

    var hostBuilder = WebApiHostBuilder.CreateHostForDependencyInjectionTests(new string[0]);

    var host = hostBuilder.Build();

    Assert.NotNull(host);
}
```

The problem is that now that I've moved to .net 8, I cannot use a startup class.  Trying to add it to the builder.WebHost causes an [ASP0010 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0010?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

My new program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.ConfigureSwagger();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

What I'm looking to do is somehow start the api application from a unit test and let any errors throw for remediation.